# Can't send email from Grails services

Tags: email, grails, service, controller

I want my program to send email from the service layer when certain actions executed.
I was able to do that from the controller, but I want it to be done in the services.

Here is what I did:

1. Installed Grails mail plugin  (http://grails.org/plugin/mail)
2. My controller code

   ```
   package mypackage

   class SendController {

       def notifierService

       def index = { }

       def send = {
           notifierService.contactUser(params.userName, params.email)
       }
   }
   ```
3. My service code:

   ```
   package mypackage

   class NotifierService {

       boolean transactional = false

       def mailService

       def contactUser(userName, email) {
           mailService.sendMail{
               to email
               from "me"
               subject "Testing email system"
               body "Hi ${userName} from a service!"
           }
           render "test"
       }
   }
   ```

When I run app it gives me this error:

> cannot resolve symbol 'params' in SendController.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the error you are getting is referring to send closure? Is there anywhere else in your controller u are using params ? also that render "test" should located in your controller

Comment: Do you see the same issue if you use `send` as a method `send()` instead of a closure `send={}` after answering @Alidad?

Comment: yes, the error refers to send closure. but when I tried to just render the params in send controller, it worked fine, so I think that the error message is misleading.

Comment: sorry, it was the error I was getting before, now it gives me this:
Class
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
No signature of method:mypackage.NotifierService.render() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [test] Possible solutions: every(), find(), getAt(java.lang.String), find(groovy.lang.Closure), every(groovy.lang.Closure)
  Again, sorry for misleading you.

Comment: The error message is accurate. Services don't define render methods, Controllers do.

Comment: yes, you are right! removing render from service fixed the problem. thanks everyone for help!